# Having trouble connecting Visual studio with github

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I use Visual studios and I can see the changes and deleted code that I write, commit etc. But when commiting it won't update the change to github or the other teams working environments (they don't see my commited code). I can see their changes through GitHub though but the code doesn't reach my Visual studio. Is there a simple fix for this?

Comment: Do you push your code after commit?

Comment: do you have pull the repository? and you saw, when you have change a file with `git status` the changed file there??

Comment: @Julian I get cant push refs to remote. Try running pull first to integrate your changes after first commiting and then pushing